# Ecto query for date range

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have to query the date range on the basis of timestamps in the model.
what i have tried so far is

```
str="2017-12-18"
{:ok, ed}=Ecto.Date.cast(str)
ed= ed |> Ecto.Date.from_erl  |> NaiveDate.from_erl!
Repo.all(from l in Log, where: l.inserted_at == ^ed)
```

However the date in the postgres is in the form of datetime, e.g. 2017-12-18 19:58:01.414.

but i just want to query on the date and not the time. However if i use `Ecto.DateTime` and `NaiveDateTime` and pass the acurate datetime in string, it works. but i just want to match on the date, instead. How can that be possible? 
Thanks

Comment: `ed |> Ecto.Date.from_erl  |> NaiveDate.from_erl!` can not be a real code, please correct the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast the field to a date using a `fragment` and then compare that:

```
Repo.all(from l in Log, where: fragment("?::date", l.inserted_at) == ^ed)
```

Comment: Thanks, how can i use it in Bindingless operation

Comment: I don't think this can be done with a bindingless query as the LHS is a fragment.

Answer (score 2):

Given an [Date.Range](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Date.Range.html), I was able to filter my Ecto query this way, using Postgres' `between`:

```
def within_date_range(query, %Date.Range{} = date_range) do
  from p in query,
    where:
      fragment(
        "inserted_at?::date between ? and ?",
        ^date_range.first,
        ^date_range.last
      )
end
```

Which would be used like so:

```
date_range = Date.range(
  Date.from_iso8601!("2023-01-01"),
  Date.from_iso8601!("2023-01-31"),
)

Log
|> within_date_range(date_range)
|> Repo.all()
```